# Upload video directly to Vimeo.com using POST method

Tags: video, video-streaming, vimeo

I need hosting and streaming video in my project, and for now I don't want deal with coding, hosting, etc. So my choice - using some video platform, e.g. Vimeo.

Ideal API as I see it - is submit form with file directly to vimeo, and wait for callback with  video credentials, for storing it in db, etc.

And I see in Vimeo API near the same: https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/upload#post-step1 BUT after step 3 I should do step 5 `Complete the upload` but for this operation I need to know `filename` but how I can now it, if I do POST submit directly to vimeo?

Yeap, I can do ajax request, or upload video to my server and then made post request to vimeo, but I don't like this, because I don't see really sence.

Can anyone explain me where I made mistake, and how can I achieve what I need?

Thanks!